# Samsung Account Notification won't go away

Tags: samsung

I recently updated my Samsung A10e to Android 10 with OneUI 2.0. When it finished updating, I got a notification requesting me to "sign into my Samsung account to safely use some services". I forgot the password so I reset it accordingly, and then I (thought that I) finished.

Except then it gives me a notification asking "we need some more information to finish setting up your Samsung account". I enter the requested information and hit "done". Then, almost seconds after hitting "done", the notification pops up again, requesting the same thing. When I go back to the screen where I was to enter information, it still showed the information I already entered, but the notification WOULD NOT go away!

Help would be appreciated, as this notification will not go away.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I hope someone has a good answer for you.  I stopped buying Samsung devices because of issues like this.  Just because you buy a Samsung device, doesn't mean you should have to create a Samsung account.